# Don't want my messages to be recalled after somebody send them to me

Tags: outlook-2007

How can I set up my outlook, so that if somebody send me an e mail, they can not
recalled it back for any reason. I am using outlook 2007.

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft's hilarious attempt to create an [unsend function](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-recall-unsend-sent-message-microsoft-outlook-827307.html)?

Comment: "unsend function" says you can recall the messages which you had sent. but my concern is that I don't want others to recall the message which they had sent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why would you do this?

Second, there are a number of options:

1. the recall works only if the message to be recalled is unread. You can create an easy VBA script which checks the inbox every second and marks all the emails as read. You also have to leave  Tools, Options, Preferences, E-Mail Options, Tracking Options, "Process requests and responses on arrival" as unselected.
2. Possibly better solution would be to set up a server rule which moves all the incoming messages from INBOX to another folder (recalled messages are only those which remain in Inbox)